# Best way to handle a freezing thread in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a project in electronjs with vue cli.

I am making some api calls that by their nature freeze the thread they're in. The API is archaic, and I need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax this npm package to handle the response and process it to xml/json/etc.

The fact that the app is freezing when I call the api is already a horrible thing and I needed to find a viable way to have those calls running in the background. I have tried `worker_threads`, and vanilla web workers but I couldn't require this crucial `winax` package so my last resort solution was to create a new `BrowserWindow` that loads a html file that has my API calling class in its script.

The method works as I'm hiding the window that freezes but this solution comes with a lot of problems as I am not able to export that class and call it somewhere else. Because of this I am required to use the remote module, set global variables in order to handle the communication between my API responses and the other windows in my app.

I would happily include any other details that I am allowed to, however I am quite restricted by the confidentiality of my project so I'll do my best.

My question is: does this seem like something you've encountered and could point me in the right direction on how to handle those troublesome API calls?

Electron version: 8.5.5
OS: Windows 10 Pro
The app is intended to work only on Windows
I do not have any technical nodejs/electron knowledge in my company - in case I get an answer telling me to go to my senior :D